# Chrome cast extension in chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromecast

I have created  chrome packaged apps.I have to cast images using chrome cast from chrome app.My application works in chrome browser perfectly.But as a chrome packaged app it doesnot open the popup asking the device to cast on and hence not working.Can anyone suggest what can be done for this?

Comment: Have you looked through this one: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287254

Comment: But I am not at all getting what is step 3  they are discussing ... so much confusion

Comment: I think you can ask for detail on that posted question or you may post your own on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) which is the best place to answer this kind of feature request question.